# Avoid to subset the data and then merge to make calculations in dplyr

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data set like **df**:

```
df <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2002", "2007", "2001", "2002", "2004", "2007"), 
                 id = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), 
                 product = c("apple","orange", "melon", "orange", "orange", "orange", "cake", "bacon", "truffels"), 
                 market = c("CHN", "USA", "USA", "CAN", "USA", "USA", "CHL", "CHL", "ECU"), 
                 value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
```

All I want to do is to create the variable **years_id_consecutive** which is a variable that counts the number of years that a given id shows up in the data in a consecutive way. Consecutive here is defined as showing up during the last 2 years before appearing in year t. My trial goes below:

```
df_panel <- df %>%
  mutate(year = as.numeric(year)) %>%
  group_by(id, year) %>%
  summarise(value=head(value,1)) %>% #take the first row by id-year
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(nesting(id), year = full_seq(year, period = 1)) #create a balanced panel


df_panel <- df_panel %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(value_lag1 = lag(value, 1),
         value_lag2 = lag(value, 2),
         continuous = ifelse(!is.na(value) & !is.na(value_lag1) | !is.na(value) & !is.na(value_lag2), 1, 0)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  drop_na(value) %>%
  mutate(continuous_lag1 = lag(continuous, 1),
         years_id_consecutive = ifelse(continuous==0, 0, continuous+continuous_lag1),
         year = as.character(year)) %>%
  select(-value_lag1, -value_lag2, -continuous, -continuous_lag1) 
  

df_new <- left_join(df, df_panel, by = c("id", "year", "value"))
df_new[is.na(df_new)] <- 0
```

My trial in **dplyr** **cuts** the data and then **merges** the data with the original dataset. However, this method is very slow as my current data set is huge. Therefore I am looking for a solution in R base or a different method that is faster and **integrated in one chunk of code**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't need to use lag or complete, we can do it with `base:rle`and `tidyr::map2`. `rle` is to identify consecutive values and `map2` to create sequences of consecutives years.

```r
    suppressWarnings(library(tidyverse))
    
    df <- data.frame(year = c("2000", "2000", "2000", "2002", "2007", "2001", "2002", "2004", "2007"), 
                     id = c("X", "X", "X", "X", "X", "Z", "Z", "Z", "Z"), 
                     product = c("apple","orange", "melon", "orange", "orange", "orange", "cake", "bacon", "truffels"), 
                     market = c("CHN", "USA", "USA", "CAN", "USA", "USA", "CHL", "CHL", "ECU"), 
                     value = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9))
    
    df_teste <- 
    df |> 
      arrange(id,year) |>
      group_by(id) |> 
      mutate(year = as.integer(year) ,
             id_consecutive = year %in% c(year + 1, year + 2),
             year = as.character(year))
    
    rle_year <- df_teste$id_consecutive |> rle() 
    #> Run Length Encoding
    #> lengths: int [1:5] 3 1 2 2 1
    #> values : logi [1:5] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE

    years_consecutive <- unlist( map2(rle_year$values, rle_year$lengths, ~ if(.x) seq(1,.y) else rep(0,.y)) )
    
    df_teste$years_consecutive <- years_consecutive
    df_teste
    #> # A tibble: 9 × 7
    #> # Groups:   id [2]
    #>   year  id    product  market value id_consecutive years_consecutive
    #>   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <lgl>                      <dbl>
    #> 1 2000  X     apple    CHN        1 FALSE                          0
    #> 2 2000  X     orange   USA        2 FALSE                          0
    #> 3 2000  X     melon    USA        3 FALSE                          0
    #> 4 2002  X     orange   CAN        4 TRUE                           1
    #> 5 2007  X     orange   USA        5 FALSE                          0
    #> 6 2001  Z     orange   USA        6 FALSE                          0
    #> 7 2002  Z     cake     CHL        7 TRUE                           1
    #> 8 2004  Z     bacon    CHL        8 TRUE                           2
    #> 9 2007  Z     truffels ECU        9 FALSE                          0

    Created on 2023-01-20 with reprex v2.0.2
```

`years_consecutive` isn't grouped, so is best to order the df before

**EDIT**

We can write everything in one chunk of code using `nest`

```r
df |> 
  group_by(id) |> 
  mutate(year = as.integer(year) ,
         id_consecutive = year %in% c(year + 1, year + 2),
         year = as.character(year)) |> 
  nest() |> 
  mutate(rle_year = map(data, ~rle(.x$id_consecutive) ), 
         years_consecutive =
           map(rle_year, ~ unlist(map2(.x$values, .x$lengths, ~ if(.x) seq(1,.y) else rep(0,.y)) ) )
         ) |> 
  unnest(c(data, years_consecutive))
#> # A tibble: 9 × 8
#> # Groups:   id [2]
#>   id    year  product  market value id_consecutive rle_year years_consecutive
#>   <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl> <lgl>          <list>               <dbl>
#> 1 X     2000  apple    CHN        1 FALSE          <rle>                    0
#> 2 X     2000  orange   USA        2 FALSE          <rle>                    0
#> 3 X     2000  melon    USA        3 FALSE          <rle>                    0
#> 4 X     2002  orange   CAN        4 TRUE           <rle>                    1
#> 5 X     2007  orange   USA        5 FALSE          <rle>                    0
#> 6 Z     2001  orange   USA        6 FALSE          <rle>                    0
#> 7 Z     2002  cake     CHL        7 TRUE           <rle>                    1
#> 8 Z     2004  bacon    CHL        8 TRUE           <rle>                    2
#> 9 Z     2007  truffels ECU        9 FALSE          <rle>                    0
```

Comment: Thanks for your wise answer. However, I would like to sum the TRUE's (by id) if they are consecutive. Otherwise, the count will start from 0. Any idea for this without lagging?

Comment: Could also be integrated in one chunk of code deriving from df %>%... instead of creating df_teste, rle_year, and years_consecutive?

Comment: @vog `years_consecutive` already has this information, my disclaimer was, if there were true values consecutives from diferent groups it would count as consecutives years, but this won't happen if you sort the years first, as the first year of each group will never be a consecutive year

Comment: I will edit the answer to use one chunk of code with `nest`

Comment: This is very helpful. Thanks a lot! Could you explains the lines of the edit ?